# RegEx over multipe lines

Tags: html, regex

I want to extract only the "Mlody" string from the below code. Matching should start from `<dt>User</dt>` and end at `</dd>` on the next line. I need some help on the RegEx code required. HTML code is below.

```
<dl>
<dt>User</dt>
<dd><a href="/users/837">Mlody</a></dd>
<dd></dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: I have tried this <dt>User</dt>(.*?)</dd>

Comment: I am using it in Google App Script

Comment: your regex looks ok, what is the problem?

Comment: It does not work across the newline

Comment: From the doc: ". any character, including newline (s=true)", so I guess you have to make sure that s is set to true in the configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As a general rule, you shouldn't use a regex to match/parse the HTML text.**

Instead, try a DOM parser (if available) and search for the tag you need, and then search the text content of those results with a regex if you need to match against the contents.

Only if you don't have any other option decide to use regex.

You can try following regex for matching multiline text:

```
<dt>User</dt>((?:.|[\r\n])*?)</dd>
```